# Why does IfBooleanT not compile when NewDocumentEnvironment star not present?

Tags: environments, tcolorbox, minted

I'm trying to define a `\NewDocumentEnvironment` called *{codesnippet}* which generates a *{minted}* code block, wrapped in a *{tcolorbox}* environment for styling. My environment takes two *{xparse}* arguments: `{ s o }`

`s` is meant to enable the display of the *{minted}* line numbers (*linenos* option), when the star is present;
`o` is meant to pass the Pygments syntax highlighting language to *{minted}*, if necessary.

Here's my environment definition:

```tex
\NewDocumentEnvironment{codesnippet}{ s o }
    {%
        \VerbatimEnvironment%
        \begin{tcolorbox}[
            enhanced,
            left=5mm, arc=0.25mm,
            borderline={0.25mm}{0mm}{NavyBlue!15!white},
            colback=bgblue!15!white,
            colframe=white]%
        \begin{minted}[%
            numbersep=6pt,fontsize=\small,breaklines,%
            \IfBooleanT {#1}
                {linenos}]{#2}}
        {\end{minted}\end{tcolorbox}
    }
```

I use this environment further down, once **with** the star and once **without** the star.

**With** the star:

```tex
\begin{codesnippet}*[docker]
    %Numbered code here.
\end{codesnippet}
```

**Without** the star:

```tex
\begin{codesnippet}[tex]
    %Code without numbers here.
\end{codesnippet}
```

Now, whenever I try to compile this file, I get the following error:

```
! Package keyval Error:  undefined.  

l.19 \begin{codesnippet}[tex]
```

If I add the star to the second *{codesnippet}* block, everything compiles just fine.

Am I not understanding the usage of `\IfBooleanT` correctly? Based on my code, shouldn't it add the *linenos* option IF the star is present and IF NOT present then do nothing?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! When `minted` examines the options it does no expansion.

Comment: You are aware that `tcolorbox` comes with its own `documentation` and `code` display features?

Comment: Hi guys. Thank you for your replies!

I've read about the fact that `minted` doesn't expand the code and I've also read the `tcolorbox` documentation, thoroughly. I know that `tcolorbox` uses the `minted` package for code display.

I've reached the above code from another (much simpler) SX answer that was achieving basically what I wanted. 

I'll give the `tcolorbox` documentation another read in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `minted` evaluates options, no expansion is done, so

```
\begin{minted}[
  numbersep=6pt,
  fontsize=\small,
  breaklines,
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{linenos}]{#2}
}
```

does not set the `linenos` option. You can use `\setminted` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{codesnippet}{ s m }
  {%
   \VerbatimEnvironment
   \begin{tcolorbox}[
     enhanced,
     left=5mm,
     arc=0.25mm,
     borderline={0.25mm}{0mm}{red!15!white},
     colback=blue!15!white,
     colframe=white
   ]
   \IfBooleanT{#1}{\setminted{linenos}}
   \begin{minted}[numbersep=6pt,fontsize=\small,breaklines]{#2}%
  }
  {\end{minted}\end{tcolorbox}}

\begin{document}

\begin{codesnippet}*{docker}
abc
def
ghi
\end{codesnippet}

\begin{codesnippet}{docker}
abc
def
ghi
\end{codesnippet}

\end{document}
```

Notes. I changed `o` into `m`; if you want to use an optional argument, then it should be `O{<default>}`, where `<default>` stands for the normally required lexer. I also changed the colors (you didn't show their definitions).

[image]

A different implementation with `\NewTCBListing`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted}

\NewTCBListing{codesnippet}{ s m }
 {
  listing engine=minted,
  listing only,
  enhanced,
  left=5mm,
  arc=0.25mm,
  borderline={0.25mm}{0mm}{red!15!white},
  colback=blue!15!white,
  colframe=white,
  minted language=#2,
  minted options/.expanded={
    numbersep=6pt,
    fontsize=\noexpand\small,
    breaklines,
    \IfBooleanT{#1}{linenos,}
  },
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{codesnippet}*{docker}
abc
def
ghi
\end{codesnippet}

\begin{codesnippet}{docker}
abc
def
ghi
\end{codesnippet}

\end{document}
```

However, I think that passing the `linenos` option is better; the following implementation allows also any other options for `minted`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted}

\NewTCBListing{codesnippet}{ O{} m }
 {
  listing engine=minted,
  listing only,
  enhanced,
  left=5mm,
  arc=0.25mm,
  borderline={0.25mm}{0mm}{red!15!white},
  colback=blue!15!white,
  colframe=white,
  minted language=#2,
  minted options/.expanded={
    numbersep=6pt,
    fontsize=\noexpand\small,
    breaklines,
    #1
  },
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{codesnippet}[linenos]{docker}
abc
def
ghi
\end{codesnippet}

\begin{codesnippet}{docker}
abc
def
ghi
\end{codesnippet}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works flawlessly! Thank you! And your explanation finally made me understand that the expansion does not happen **only during options evaluation**, is that correct? I see that, as soon as the options evaluation bracket is closed, `IfBooleanT` expands just fine. Thanks again!

Comment: @EmanuelSandu I added a different implementation using `\NewTCBListing`.

Comment: your last solution works great and is very elegant. I'll be using it! Thanks again!

Comment: Is there any documentation that I can read up on about the `/.expanded` token you've used in your second example, @egreg ? I would like to further understand how it works.

Comment: @EmanuelSandu That's in the PGF manual.